# Not returning what's intended

Tags: java, constructor, calling-convention

I am having trouble printing out the first and last name scanned in (`fname1`, `lname1`). I have to create 6 objects and these are two that I can't seem to even start with. Also, if I enter anything except "yes" or "y", it will not loop back to the radiobuttons I inserted above the snippet. How do I fix this?

This is what prints out in the output window:

```
[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=350,height=200]]
```

```
public class Cabin_Selector
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame cabin_selection = new JFrame("Select Your Cabin"); //Prompts the user
        cabin_selection.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Close the Frame when exiting

        Project2_JoshuaLucas selection = new Project2_JoshuaLucas("", "", "", "", "", "", "", 0.00); //Call the constructor for the Project2_JoshuaLucas class
        cabin_selection.getContentPane().add(selection); //put the object in the current pane of the jframe

        cabin_selection.pack();  //size the frame
        cabin_selection.setVisible(true);  //make the frame visible

    }  //end main method
}  //end class

if (source == cabin1)
{
    cabin1.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    cabin2.setBackground(Color.gray);
    cabin3.setBackground(Color.gray);
    cabin4.setBackground(Color.gray);
    cabin5.setBackground(Color.gray);
    cabin6.setBackground(Color.gray);
    cabin7.setBackground(Color.gray);
    cabin8.setBackground(Color.gray);
    cabin9.setBackground(Color.gray);
    cabin10.setBackground(Color.gray);
    suite1.setBackground(Color.red);
    suite2.setBackground(Color.red);

    System.out.println("Your choice is Cabin 11-1, would you like to designate this as your room?");
    info1 = scan_in.nextLine();
    info1 = info1.toLowerCase();

    if ( info1.equals ("yes") || info1.equals ("y"))
    {
        continues=true;   
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of people in your cabin (*Maximum number of people is 2*)");
        cabin_people = scan_in.nextInt();
        scan_in.nextLine();

        while(continues)
        {
            switch (cabin_people)
            {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("There is one passenger within the cabin. (You will pay an EXTRA 45% because of the empty passenger slot)");
                continues=false;
                onepassenger=true;
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("There are two passenger within this cabin.");
                continues=false;
                twopassenger=true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please try again. Remember, the maximum amount of passengers allowed is 2.");
                System.out.println("How many passengers are staying within this cabin?");
                cabin_people=scan_in.nextInt();
                scan_in.nextLine();
                continues=true;
            }//Closes the Switch
        }//Closes the while(continues) loop

        while(onepassenger)
        {
            System.out.println("Please state your FIRST name: ");
            fname1=scan_in.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please state your LAST name: ");
            lname1=scan_in.nextLine();

            onepassenger=false;
            Project2_JoshuaLucas passenger1 = new Project2_JoshuaLucas (fname1, lname1, "", "", "", "", "", 0.00);
            System.out.println(passenger1);
        } //Closes while(1passenger)
        while(twopassenger)
        {
            System.out.println("Please state your FIRST name: ");
            fname1=scan_in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please state your LAST name: ");
            lname1=scan_in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the second passenger's FIRST name: ");
            fname2=scan_in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the second passenger's LAST name: ");
            lname2=scan_in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the city you live in: ");
            cob=scan_in.nextLine();

            twopassenger=false;
        } //Closes while(2passenger)
    } //Closes yes | y
    else 
        System.out.println("Please select another cabin");
    continues=false;
} //Closes source==cabin1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your displaying the `toString()` method returned by one of your Swing components -- likely a JPanel since it uses FlowLayout, and the solution is:

- Don't pass a Swing component into a `System.out.println(...)` call,
- Instead print out the state of your key non-GUI objects, called "model" objects because they model the behavior and state of your program.
- Make sure that these classes have a decent `public String toString()` method override, so what they print out makes sense.

You ask:

> What is a model object?

If you are creating an airplane GUI for instance, you'll likely need to create several classes, some of the GUI component classes, others non. The model classes could include:

- Passenger
- Airplane
- AirplaneSeat
- ....

These model classes will contain information about themselves, such as a Passenger will have a name, perhaps an age, a passengerNumber id number... The Airplane will have a collection of first class AirplaneSeats and likewise for coach. AirplaneSeat will have a boolean occupied field, and perhaps a Passenger field to tell who occupies what seat. But none of these classes will contain GUI component code, none will extend JPanel or JFrame or such.

Then you'll likely have view classes that do either extend GUI components or contain them, and they will display the state of the model classes above. You tried to print out the toString() of a view class, one that does not override the toString() method.

A side recommendation: you appear to be trying to mix a Swing GUI program with a console program, and you're not going to want to do this. Instead you should have all user interaction and output in the GUI, not in console, except perhaps for simple debugging purposes, but nothing more.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a year 1 CSCI Major and I'm extremely new to java. What is a model object? And Is override just @Override?

Comment: @JoshuaLucas: see edit. Also consider improving your question by showing which line prints out the offending information and by posting the complete String that's printed out, since it looks like some has been left out.